# ReactJS - How to parse JSX variable in JSON element

Tags: html, reactjs

I get some values from a `JSON` file :

`<div className={style.header}>Header</div>`

i use `html-react-parser` to parse the html. But this way does not transform my `style.myHeader`

Here a simple exemple of my code :

```
import style from ./theme/style.css;
import Parser from 'html-react-parser';

let html = myJsonValue;

render(
    <div> {Parser(html)} </div>
);
```

Thanks for help

Comment: `<div className={style.header}>Header</div>` - why do you call it JSON? Or did you mean `style` is JSON (which is also not)?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko it's just a example so i just copy/paste the value of my json element.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify `myJsonValue` at the source, you'll need to use the Parser [options](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/html-react-parser#options) to replace the className with the value you want.